# Where is libdispatch AKA Grand Central Dispatch imported?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch, libdispatch

I am reading [Apple's documentation on Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH100-SW1), more specifically on NSOperationQueue vs a Dispatch Queue.

They say this:

> "An operation queue is the Cocoa equivalent of a concurrent dispatch
>   queue ..."

Which made me wonder, if NSOperationQueue is available through the Cocoa framework, how is GCD available?

When I call `dispatch_after...`, why is it that I don't need to `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>`?

How does the compiler recognize GCD selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `dispatch/dispatch.h` header file for using GCD APIs.

[dispatch manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/dispatch):

```
$ man dispatch
dispatch(3)              BSD Library Functions Manual              dispatch(3)

NAME
     dispatch -- the dispatch framework

SYNOPSIS
     #include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
```

Cocoa headers also import the header file (For example, NSOperation.h), so in most cases you don't need to import the header file explicitly.

Comment: But if you look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959007/files-imported-when-importing-foundation-foundation-h-for-cocoa 

Cocoa.h doesn't contain dispatch.h-- yet I can still make dispatch calls without importing dispatch.h?

Comment: Cocoa.h imports Foundation.h, right? Foundation.h imports NSOperation.h that I mentioned in the answer. So you already imports dispatch.h.

Comment: Right.  So NSOperation.h imports dispatch.h?  But my confusion is that it seems NSOperationQueues and Dispatch Queues are two entirely separate things

Comment: See this thread too: stackoverflow.com/questions/9019327/… when is libSystem linked?
If I look at the build phases, it doesn't include libSystem with libraries to be linked, so I can only assume Xcode automatically links some system libraries.  Is there any way I can see a list of those?

Comment: NSOperation.h uses `dispatch_queue_t` type. That's why NSOperation.h imports dispatch.h. That's it. No other reasons.

Comment: Nvm figured it out.  it looks like dispatch.h is available through the Base SDK-- which has it's headers available through /usr/include.  Then it's probably one of the first things linked after compiling

Comment: I was afraid you would just leave after I did that-- because it still didn't make total sense to me.  Accepting now ;)