# Unity Xcode errors

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I made a mobile game with Unity, and that game is avaliable on Google Play Store. Everything works fine. That game had a admob.

Now, when I build my Unity project to xcode, I have list of warnings and errors. Here is a pic: http://oi68.tinypic.com/4ilvl0.jpg (my scripts are made with c# and javascript)

What can I do?
How can I put game to App Store? Why is everything good with android build, but don't with iOS?

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: the warnings are not pretty, but the more important part is the error - show that one. Regarding the "why" - because for iOS you use objective-c and swift, everything else is interpreted, or translated or whatever, opening a ton of ways for bugs to get in - the only way around is to build your app natively.

Comment: Afaik is quite normal to have a lot of warnings, when using unity to create an Xcode project.. But please show us the error message, and not one of those warnings, to help you get the build working. ;-) Android vs iOS, thats just some very different platforms (java vs objc / JIT vs AOT)

Comment: Try clicking on the red exclamation mark in the top and take a screenshot of that error. I think that is the one that will tell us (you) what is wrong

Comment: Here is error: http://oi64.tinypic.com/nyvgco.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Go to the build settings for your Xcode target and search for "bitcode".  Turn it off and rebuild.

Comment: Now, I had these problems http://oi64.tinypic.com/91jqsk.jpg
I tried change @import to #import.

Comment: #import syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044360/import-using-angle-brackets-and-quote-marks

Comment: says: "Foundation" file not found :(

Comment: Because "Foundation" isn't the name of a file, maybe?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959007/files-imported-when-importing-foundation-foundation-h-for-cocoa

Comment: I need this for AdMob. Is your link for that or?

Comment: Not specifically.  Your latest error came from trying to import the Cocoa Foundation and getting the syntax wrong.  That's what the link is about.

Comment: I ask because my error says now: "GoogleMobileAds" file not found

Comment: I haven't used that.  Doesn't it come with any documentation or examples?

Comment: I followed documentations, but this is the problem. I will try again everything. Thank you Phillip very much for your help :)